# PHP: Mockery Mock variable $user = Auth::user()

Tags: php, laravel, mockery

So, I am trying to mock a service method.

In my service file:

```
/**
 * Return all Api Keys for current user.
 *
 * @return Collection
 */
public function getApiKeys(): Collection
{
    $user = Auth::user();

    return ApiKey::where('org_id', $user->organizationId)->get();
}
```

How do I mock this?

```
<?php


namespace App\Services;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use Mockery as m;

class ApiKeysServiceTest extends TestCase
{
public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();

    /* Mock Dependencies */
}

public function tearDown()
{
    m::close();
}

public function testGetApiKeys()
{
    /* How to test? $user = Auth::user() */
    $apiKeysService->getApiKeys();
}
```

}

In my TestCase class I have:

```
public function loginWithFakeUser()
{
    $user = new GenericUser([
        'id' => 1,
        'organizationId' => '1234'
    ]);

    $this->be($user);
}
```

What I want to do is test this method. Maybe this involves restructuring my code so that $user = Auth::user() is not called in the method. If this is the case, any thoughts as to where it should go?

Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Use a factory to create a user, and then use `$this->actingAs($user);` See https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/http-tests#session-and-authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `testGetApiKeys` method you're not setting up the world. Make a mock user (using a factory as suggested in the comments `factory('App\User')->create()`), then setup an apiKey again using the factory, then call the method and assert it's what you've setup. An example with your code

```
public function loginWithFakeUser()
{
    $user = factory('App\User')->create();

    $this->be($user);
}

public function testApiSomething()
{
    $this->loginWithFakeUser();

    // do something to invoke the api...
    // assert results
}
```

A good blueprint for the test structure is:

- Given we have something (setup all the needed components)
- If the user does some action (visits a page or whatever)
- Then ensure the result of the action is what you expect (for example the status is 200)